# Initialize a heap object using constructed non-heap object

Tags: c++

So, I have class A, and I have created object `A obj1` , but now I want to create a heap object using new operator `A *obj2 = new A(int x)` , but using the data from obj1 without having access to members of obj1.

Can I initialize members of obj2 using obj1 without having access to obj1 members (public access or through get functions)?

(I'm sorry if my question is...incomprehensible)

Comment: Normally you have a publicly acessible copy-constructor, and so `A *obj2 = new A(obj1);` uses that constructor to create the object. Look up copy-constructors.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I initialize members of obj2 using obj1

In your example, `obj2` has no members because it's a pointer. I suppose that you want the dynamic object to be a copy instead.

If the type is copy-constructible and you have access to it, then you can simply use copy initialisation. Here is an example:

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<A>(obj1);
```

P.S.

- Don't use bare owning pointers.
- Avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. The copy constructor will need access, but it can access private member variables.

```
class A {
  private:
    int x;
};

void foo(A stack_allocated) {
  A *heap_allocated = new A(stack_allocated);
}
```